# Mixed content error after adding SSL certificate

Tags: plugins, jquery, ssl

I'm having problems on a website after adding an SSL certificate. These are the WhyNoPadlock results: https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/7193cea2-78e7-4bc7-9581-2af7f90bd15d

What I’ve done so far:

1. Changed all to HTTPS in WP settings
2. Used Better Search Replace to replace all instances of HTTP with HTTPS.

This hasn't fixed things and any advice on how else to resolve these hard and soft failures very appreciated.

Another problem is that since adding the SSL certificate, the slider which should appear on the home page has disappeared. It uses an old plugin called Cross Slide Cross Fade, which hasn’t been updated for a few years. I’m presuming this may also be a result of a mixed content error but any other thoughts on this also appreciated. I'm hoping it's simply a question of sorting out any http/https conflicts in it but also wonder if push comes to shove if it would be better to uninstall it and try using a more modern slider plugin?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you go through your theme and plugins for hardcoded URLs? You tried to change everything in the database but didn't change any of the files. Also, using the jQuery from the CDN isn't great and it's using an insecure URL, don't deregister/re-register jQuery

Comment: It looks like the stray jQuery is from the cross-slider plugin, yes, and it won't work with WordPress's included jQuery because it's trying to use `$()` not `jQuery()`. The plugin changelog says it should be fixed in version 1.6 - can you get hold of a later version? There's a version 2.0.5 in Subversion if you can get it from there. Alternatively you can probably just edit the http:// to https:// in the plugin, or change the two `$(` to `jQuery(` and it should work again.

Comment: Thank you both. Must admit I'm more of frontend designer with knowledge of HTML and CSS and jQuery is somewhat beyond me! I think in the log run it is going to be better to switch to a more up to date slideshow plugin. I would like to try and make a temporary fix if I can. 
Rup, I did a search for the version you mention in Subversion but couldn't find it - are you able to send a link to it please? I can see that I can edit the plugin code - you said there are two $( which I need to change to jQuery( -  are they on particular lines of the code in the file jQuery.cross-slide.js? 
Many thanks

Comment: Tom, when you say go through the theme & plugins for hardcoded URLs, does that mean scan through the code & see if I can spot any random HTTP links & update them to HTTPS manually? I tried this with the soft failures re links to social media icons in footer document but got an error message within Wordpress: 'Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as using SFTP.' Is only way to update these URLs editing the file locally & uploading the new version via Filezilla? Steph

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure how the version numbers are tracked in Subversion. I was looking at trunk which says 2.0.5: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress/trunk/ You can just download files from there if you don't have an svn client installed. I don't know about editing files through WordPress sorry, I would normally SSH into the machine if I could, else probably SFTP yes.

Comment: Hi Tom - just to update as you'll see below - using Filezilla I made changes to the areas where hard and soft failures were showing up in WhyNoPadlock and this has now resolved the mixed content errors. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have version 1.6.0 of the crossslide plugin. (I'd guessed 1.5.2 since the changelog said 1.6.0 fixed this, but it didn't.)

You can fix this by

1. unticking the 'Default jQuery' option in the plugin configuration, which removes the ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js include
2. replacing `$(` with `jQuery(` on lines 101 and 102, i.e. instead of

   ```
    $(function(){
        $('#crslideshow').crossSlide({
   ```

   you should have

   ```
   jQuery(function(){
       jQuery('#crslideshow').crossSlide({
   ```

   (This is because WordPress sets up jQuery in noConflict mode by default, where it does not define itself as $. Including the second jQuery script did set up $ with the old version.)

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/RupW/997dc746305f44aa3de1b4aba82448e6#file-crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress-php-L91) of roughly what you should be left with. (There is another set of `$(` to `jQuery(` changes on lines 120-133, but you don't need those for the mode you're running the plugin in.) It should now work again. The original CrossSlide author [does recommend using something more modern](https://github.com/tobia/CrossSlide), but it should continue to work fine.

You could also upgrade the plugin to 2.0+ which would already contain this fix; it's not available for download anymore, but the files are in subversion (see [the 'Development' tab of the plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress/#developers)).

Comment: Hi Rup - many thanks for this. I made those changes to the code in the plugin file but unfortunately the slider still doesn't appear. It looks as if all things are pointing to starting afresh with a new slider. The good news though is that updating that code and also updating the links in the footer document has resolved the mixed content errors and the padlock now shows on Chrome and elsewhere, so a breakthrough on that score! https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/f35da1ed-7c06-4a41-ba9f-b78a56025161 Appreciate your time and it has been helpful to clarify that the plugin may just be too old.

Comment: Oops, sorry: the problem now is that you're echoing two `<script src='` where you should only have one, somewhere around line 105 I'd guess. It should go straight from that into the setting and echoing $x code.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this.Yes, I found a duplicate - these were right next to each other and so I took out one, which was echo "<script src=' ". However, the slider is still not appearing unfortunately.

Comment: Now you're missing the script URL, the two lines that started $x= I think.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll have to ask you to bear with me as I'm getting a bit baffled! The script URL was this URL which I took out? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js

Comment: Yes, but it now looks like you've lost the jquery.cross-slide.js too. It should look like this: https://gist.github.com/RupW/193c55a00c7de1ffa9df21151009c9db#file-crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress-php-L105 (assuming it was 1.5.2 you had to start with!) And sorry I ought to have posted a gist in the first place.

Comment: Ah, actually, totally my bad - I was focusing so much on the code, I forgot to check the version & see I have 1.6.0 installed. My apologies. Thanks so much for the link to the gist - that makes it very clear.  I've tried making a few changes based on looking at that but in fact realise I may be taking it off track as it's a different version.  Making the first changes you suggested worked so well in terms of resolving the mixed content error so I thought I was going in the right direction.. It being 1.6.0, is there anything that still jumps out as making the slider fail to appear? Many thanks

Comment: Oh right sorry, I see how I've confused things. This is what you want now: https://gist.github.com/RupW/997dc746305f44aa3de1b4aba82448e6#file-crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress-php-L91 You can leave the ajax.googleapis.com line alone, and turn it off by unchecking 'Default jQuery' in the plugin options, and the only other change you need to make now is the two `$(` -> `jQuery(` on lines 101 and 102.

Comment: Ah, thanks for sticking with it! I'm delighted to say it's now sorted - I had another idea which was when putting back the URL just to also change the http to https as this had been the initial trigger for a problem and that has also helped resolved things. The slider is back - Phew! Really appreciate your time helping me sort this out.